# Showing images in carrierwave with many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to build a simple Rails app where a user can add many images to an idea they have. I've set up a many to many on a table ImageIdeas and images can have many ideas, ideas can have many images.

Having a hard time understand this error

> The asset "" is not present in the asset pipeline.

Here is my ideas controller

```
  class IdeasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in?
  before_action :idea_current_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @idea = Idea.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @idea = @user.ideas.new(idea_params)
    @images = Image.all
    if @idea.save
      redirect_to user_idea_path(@user, @idea)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def index
    @ideas = Idea.all
  end

  def show
    @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
    @user = @idea.user
  end

  def edit
    @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
    @user = @idea.user
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def update
     @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
     @user = @idea.user
     if @idea.update(idea_params)
       flash[:notice] = "Success"
       redirect_to user_idea_path(@user, @idea)
     else
       flash[:notice] = "Try again"
       render :edit
     end
  end

  def destroy
    @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
    @user = @idea.user
    @idea.destroy
    redirect_to user_ideas_path(@user)
  end

  private

  def idea_params
    params.require(:idea).permit(:user_id, :name, :category_id)
  end

  def idea_current_user
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

Here is the app/views/ideas/new.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
<%= link_to "My Profile", user_path(@user) %>
<%= link_to "My Ideas", user_ideas_path %>
<div class = 'new-idea-form'>
  <%= form_for [@user, @idea] do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= select(:idea, :category_id, options_for_select(@categories.collect do |c|
                                                        [c.name, c.id] end)) %>

    <% @images.each do |image| %>

    <div class="image_<%= image.id %>">

      <%= check_box_tag image.title %>
      <%= image_tag image.image.to_s%>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit%>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="image-selection">

</div>
```

and the show

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
<% @user.ideas.each do |idea| %>

<%= idea.name %><br>

<%= image_tag idea.images %>
<%= link_to "Edit Idea", edit_user_idea_path(@user)%><br>
<%= link_to "Delete Idea", user_idea_path(@user), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

At a loss and deadline is in the morning. Hopefully, a night owl catches this but if not, would love to see how it's solved. Thanks.

Comment: could you tell me where this error occurred? i mean at which step?

Comment: i believe this is happening at the view level. I decided to ditch carrierwave and just use plain old strings and got it working with a little more information after the check_box_tag

  <% @images.each do |image| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "images[]", image.id, checked = false, id: "image_#{image.id}" %>
      <%= image_tag image.image%>

     <% end %>
is working for me now. check_box_tag takes up to 4 arguments and the attribute image for image could have been better named 'url_path' however now the data is getting passed along